# Run scrapy multiple spiders concurrently

Tags: python, scrapy, scheduler, scrapyd

I have 100 spiders within the same scrapy project, what is the best way to run them all concurrently, every 8hours, using some kind of a scheduler? The data scraped from all spiders are inserted into the same database table.

Comment: schedule them on crontab